# g++ flex and bison ‘yylex’ was not declared in this scope

Tags: c++, bison, flex-lexer

I'm new in flex and bison.
please help when I compile my code I got`‘yylex’ was not declared in this scope`
this is my sample.ll file :

```
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}
%%
[ \t\n]         /*do nothing*/
("//")(.)*      { cout << "comments" << endl; }
"("         { cout << "start (" << endl; }
")"         { cout << "end )" << endl; }
"+"         { cout << "+ detected" << endl; }
"-"         { cout << "- detected" << endl; }
"/"         { cout << "/ detected" << endl; }
"*"         { cout << "* detected" << endl; }
"="         { cout << "= detected" << endl; }
"=="            { cout << "==" << endl; }
"<"         { cout << "<" << endl; }
"<="            { cout << "<=" << endl; }
">"         { cout << ">" << endl; }
">="            { cout << ">=" << endl; }
"!="            { cout << "!=" << endl; }
("\"")([a-zA-Z0-0\ ]*)("\"")    { cout << "string : " << yytext << endl; }
[0-9]+          { cout << "int = " << yytext << endl; }
([0-9]+)(".")([0-9]+)   { cout << "double = " << yytext << endl; }
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*    { cout << "a varible or error : " << yytext << endl; }
"."         { cout << ". detected" << endl; }
.           { cout << "unknown : " << yytext <<  endl; }
%%
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    // lex through the input:
    yylex();
}
```

and my sample.y file is :

```
%start init
%token NUMBER
%{
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
%}
%%
init : exp
;
exp : term
| exp '+' term { cout << "+"; }
| exp '-' term { cout << "-"; }
;
term : factor
| term '*' factor { cout << "*"; }
| term '/' factor { cout << "/"; }
;
factor : NUMBER { cout << $1; }
| '('exp')'
;
%%
#include "lex.yy.cc"
```

I compile .l file with `flex -+ sample.l` and .y file with `bison -L c++ sample.y` and when I run `g++ sample.tab.cc` I got that error
I tried `int yylex();` and `void yyerror(char const*);` to fix but I got an other error `error: too many arguments to function ‘int yylex()`
please help me

Comment: Take a few steps back, and first learn how to build project with multiple source files. The solution is *not* to `#include` source files into each other. Use header files, object files, and linking. Perhaps learn to use `make` as well as a way to automate the building.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to use the C++ templates, you will need to use completely different interfaces. These are described in the [Flex](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Cxx.html#Cxx) and [Bison](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Parsers) manuals, and your first step will be to read through that and adapt your code accordingly.

If you just want to use C++ (because, apparently, you're more comfortable writing `cout << s << endl;` than `printf("%s\n", s);`), you can remove the options asking for the use of C++ templates (`-+` and `-L C++`). Then you will get the familiar interface, including `yylex`. You'll need  to explicitly specify the filenames for the output files (eg. `-o calc.lex.cc` and `-o calc.tab.cc`). The C templates will compile fine with a C++ compiler but you can only use POD as your semantic type.